# in list the value of map being stored is of object type

Tags: java, list, dictionary

I have a map and that map's contents are added to a list. The issue that I found in
debugging is that in the list the objects are added (not their values) which should not be happening.

Code which is adding the data into map:

```
 List<Pair> pairList = new ArrayList<Pair>();
 Map<Long, Integer> result = new LinkedHashMap<Long, Integer>();
 for (Object[] arr : list) {
    result.put((Long) arr[0], (Integer) arr[1]);
 }
```

Code which is transferring data from map into the list:

```
for(Map.Entry<Long, Integer> entries : result.entrySet()){
    pairList.add(new Pair(entries.getKey(), entries.getValue()));
}
```

Now the issue is that upon inspecting the list it contains the objects when it should contain the value. What is wrong with the above test case?

Comment: is `list` in the for declaration supposed to be `pairList`?

Comment: Can you post what values your have in the list? and the output?

Comment: What objects are you referring to? The `pairList` will of course contain `Pair` objects. If you are talking about the two parameters passed in to the `Pair` constructor being incorrect, then verify that the contents of the first `list` are actually what you think they are.

Answer (score 0):

Your list is of type `Pair`. You create a new `Pair` object and add that to the list. When you debug your list, you will indeed see a whole list of objects. Objects of type `Pair`. If you inspect those `Pair` objects, you'll see the values.

Answer (score 0):

Ok lets take a look at the code, shall we:

```
List<Pair> pairList = new ArrayList<Pair>();
```

This line clearly says `pairList` is a `List` of `Pair`s.

```
Map<Long, Integer> result = new LinkedHashMap<Long, Integer>();
for (Object[] arr : list) { 
    result.put((Long) arr[0], (Integer) arr[1]);
}
```

`list` is not defined in this code bit, so as far as we know you are iterating on some random list that contains Object arrays, i.e. `list` is of type `List<Object[]>`. There are some fishy bits in this code, it appears as if you shuffle stuff from one list to another, via a map. I can't imagine any reasonable scenario for that, but let's go on...

```
for(Map.Entry<Long, Integer> entries : result.entrySet()){
    pairList.add(new Pair(entries.getKey(), entries.getValue()));
}
```

Here you iterate over the entries in the map, and put them into a `Pair` object, which in turn is put into our `pairList`.

So, what you put into the list are actually `Pair`s not values of the map entries. If you need to put the values then just put in the values.

Besides the `Pair` object as it is right now, is used in the same way as a `Map.Entry`; so unless you want to do some custom magic with your `Pair`s then you don't need to have a custom class for just representing key-value pairs.

If you insist on keeping your `Pair` class, but want to be able to debug them by printing out the list, or checking the list in your IDEs debugger, then you probably want to override `toString()` method in your `Pair` class.